# Coming up with a nested loop in Python

Tags: python, nested-loops

i am a python beginner trying to come up with a nested loop but the output does not arrange the symbol in rows and columns but as a straight vertical column...
Here's my code...help me fix it

```
rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
columns = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
symbol = input("Enter the symbol to use: ")

for i in range(rows):
   for j in range(columns):
      print(symbol)
   print()
```

i've asked around  my classmates and no one seems to know the problem

Comment: [`print(symbol, end="")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 0):

You could call *print()* multiple (row * columns) times or just once per outer (rows) loop by building a string of the appropriate column length as follows:

```
rows = 10
columns = 15
symbol = "*"

for _ in range(rows):
    row = ""
    for _ in range(columns):
        row += symbol
    print(row)
```

Of course, you don't actually need a nested loop to achieve your output objective. You could just do this:

```
print(*[symbol * columns for _ in range(rows)], sep="\n")
```

Comment: `print(symbol * columns)`?

Comment: @AKX Yes but OP is specifically stating that a nested loop is required